# Using Delegate to execute code at the method entry and exit

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, delegates

I have code that does very repetitive things such as logging the method entry and exit. In between, I execute some business logic. Is there a way I could handle that with a Delegate?

Here is what I have so far. However, it is really restrictive due to the func parameters I must passing. Anybody has a better idea?

```
        Func<Func<int>, int> logAction = new Func<Func<int>, int>(func =>
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Logging...");
                return func();
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("End Logging...");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why are you logging the method entry and exit? Is this for debugging purposes?

Comment: No, it is not. I do much more than logging, I simply wanted to keep the example simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Postsharp is perfect for this- it is an Aspect Orientated Programming library that features compile time weaving, so it wont impact on performance like run time weaving. This probably doesn't explain much if your new to AOP but basically, it will allow you to declare logging on a method like this:

```
<Logging> //apply an aspect that will log entrance/exit of method
void MyMethod(params)
{
    //do something that might throw an exception (or not)
}
```

For an example (and source code) on using postsharp for logging, see http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/logging

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one of the AOP frameworks could solve your issue.

Comment: [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) has a free edition and is widely used. There is also a NuGet package for it

Answer (score 0):

```
private void LogAction(string title, Action action)
{
  Logger.Write(string.Format("Entering %0", title));

  action();

  Logger.Write(string.Format("Leaving %0", title));
}
```

Sample usage with no return value:

```
LogAction("DoSomething", () => DoSomething());
```

Sample usage with return value:

```
int intResult = 0;
LogAction("Square", () => intResult = Square(4, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to wrap everything inside of an Action and then just execute that in a method

```
public void log(Action methodToExecute)
{
    try
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Logging...");
      methodToExecute();
    }
    finally
    {
      Console.WriteLine("End Logging...");
    }

}
```

Then call it creating a generic action for your function

```
//no return
log(() => yourFunciton(optionalParmeters));

//return to something 
log(() => someVar = yourFunction(optionalParameters));
```